# Finite dimensionality of space of meromorphic sections with prescrbes poles

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Disclaimer: I hope but do not guarantee I am using correct terminology!

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold, and let $D$ be an effective divisor (by this I mean a finite formal sum over positive integers of irreducible closed hypersurfaces of $M$).

Let $E$ be an analytic vector bundle over $M$, and let $S$ be the (complex) vector space of meromorphic sections $s$ of $E$ with poles at worst $D$ (ie $\mathrm{Div}(s) + D \geq 0$).
Is it true that $S$ has finite dimension?

Comment: can I ask why the downvote? it is not homework. I know there is abundant literature, but what I could find seemed much more general than what I asked, to the point where I could not understand the statements. I would be happy with just a reference pointing me in the right direction